# HttpURLConnection: Already connected after redirect

Tags: java

I need to connect to a web application, which performs an HTTP redirect if the requested url is not mapped within the app. (for example: /users -> /users/) For authentication we use a token-based approach, so I have to send a token with each request.

I always get an `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected`, when I set the token after a redirect. Can somebody help me with this problem?

Here is what I did:

```
try {
      // setup connection
      URL url = new URL(ENDPOINT + path);
      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      connection.setRequestMethod(method.toString().toUpperCase());
      connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

      // has the request been redirected?
      if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM) {
        String newUrl = connection.getHeaderField("Location");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(ENDPOINT + newUrl).openConnection();
      }

      if (useToken) {
        connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", testToken);
      }

      // post data
      if (data != null) {
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        String json = new Gson().toJson(data);
        try (OutputStream dataStream = connection.getOutputStream()) {
          dataStream.write(json.getBytes());
        }
      }


      // retrieve response
      String body = IOUtils.toString(connection.getInputStream());
      return new TestResponse(connection.getResponseCode(), body);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage());
      return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be setting `connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true)` which will make the connection follow HTTP redirects then remove

```
// has the request been redirected?
      if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM) {
        String newUrl = connection.getHeaderField("Location");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(ENDPOINT + newUrl).openConnection();
```

I can't see from your code why you needed to set `setInstanceFollowRedirects` to false

Comment: I tried that, but then the Authorization header with the token isn't set.

Comment: when I set the "Authorization" header

Comment: I tried to close the existing connection with `connection.disconnect()` and then reconnect to the redirected endpoint, but that didn't seem to help.